# Merge txt files into one, keeping the latest rows of the duplicates that come in different files

Tags: python-3.6

The challenge here consists of merging large txt files (some are 70MB large, totalling 3GB of data), into one to be read by a BI system. Some rows are duplicated in multiple files and the merged file needs to have the latest row there.

I'm no developer, but I'm addressing this one by learning it the right way. In the meantime, I've trying to solve problems with coding. This time, I've tried a couple of solutions and the code below gives me an interesting/intriguing result:

```py
import os
import io
import pandas as pd

merged_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\txt"):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        bytes = open(file, 'rb').read()
        merged_df = merged_df.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
            bytes.decode('utf-8')), sep="\t", parse_dates=['Time']))

print(len(merged_df))
```

I keep getting this error, where it seems to get a file, but doesn't recognize it as such, nor does it write anything anywhere.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 3, in <module>
    bytes = open(file, 'rb').read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'FILENAME.txt'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `os.listdir` returns only the filenames of the files in that folder. It does not return full paths. So `open` will look for a file with that name in the folder you run the script in. You need to turn that filename into an absolute path, for example by doing

```py
file_path = os.path.join(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\txt", file)
bytes = open(file_path, 'rb').read()
```

Comment: I then have to define file, right? ...that would be...? As I mentioned, this is a beginner here and succeeding will define if I move into programming in the future - hopefully. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `file` is defined everywhere in your `for` block, so there is no need to define it.

Comment: I've been getting this error, though:
for file in os.path.join(r"C:\Users\username\Desktop\txt", file):
NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Any idea as to why this is happening!? Thank you!

Comment: Because you shouldn't change the `for` loop. The two lines I posted are supposed to replace the `bytes = ...` line, not the `for` loop.

Comment: Hi! I got this one now: 
bytes.decode('utf-8')), sep="\t", parse_dates=['Time']))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 35: invalid continuation byte

Comment: You are trying to open that file as utf-8, but it's not valid utf8. You need to find out how your file is encoded and set the right encoding. You should get more details if you google your error.